# Document retrieval from all the site collections in a web application in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am having a Web application with 18 Site Collections and these site collections are having a document library each named as `ApplicantDocs`.

Now my requirement is I need to display all the documents of the logged in user in all the 18 Site Collections at a time in the top level site as a web part.

So he doesn't see any other docs rather than the documents that belong to him.

For Single Site collection I can go with the `SPQuery` class and display. How can I achieve to display from all the site collections ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't that easily. The normal boundary in SharePoint is the site collection or the web application. You're talking about multiple site collections and hence have to resort to using custom stuff or the SharePoint Search.

One thing you didn't mention: `SPSiteDataQuery` which can query multiple webs within the same site collection, but not across multiple site collections.
- http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/401818/SharePoint-2010-SPSiteDataQuery-with-Example
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx

Custom stuff:
You will have to iterate through all site collection in the current web applications and look for the `ApplicantDocs` library. Don't forget to **dispose** each web/site you are querying!

SharePoint Search:
If your search is set up correctly you can just implement a search webpart which queries all site collections for documents for the user, now all you have to do is restrict the search to libraries named `ApplicantDocs`.